# PHP in windows 10

Tags: php, iis-10

I installed every version of PHP on windows 10 via the web platform installer with IIS10 as the web server. A simple page using PHP 7.1 as follows

```
<?php
     echo "Hello world";
```

returns back a  **[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 19ms]** message.
Any feedback as to what I could be missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Means that there's something wrong with your server configuration. It's not related to a simple hello world script.

Comment: It seems you have an error with your server, this has probably nothing to do with PHP. Can you provide your IIS configuration please?